# How to solve this Diophantus equation$(s^2=4m^2n^2+p^2$,$p^2=m^2+n^2)$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$$s^{2}=4m^{2}n^{2}+p^{2};
p^{2}=m^{2}+n^{2};
1<m<n<p<s$$
I think that this equation does not have positive Integer solution, but how to prove?

Comment: Interesting question. I tried using the standard formulae for Pythagorean triples (i.e. $(x,y,z)=(k(u^2-v^2),2kuv,k(u^2+v^2))$) and substitute those for $(m,n,p)$. This, however, doesn't seem to be very useful, since the question than becomes whether $4k^2(u^6v^2+u^2v^6-2u^4v^4)+u^4+v^4+2u^2v^2$ can ever be a square.

Comment: I caculate it in Mathematica and the progamme shows that there is no positive integer solution for m<=100000

Comment: $$
\(4k(u^{2}-v^{2})^{2}uv)^{2}+(u^{2}+v^{2})^{2}=16k^{2}(u^{5}v+uv^{5}-2u^{3}v^{3})+u^{4}+v^{4}+2u^{2}v^{2}=(s/k)^{2}.          $$

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165181/how-to-solve-this-diophantus-equations2-4m2n2p2-p2-m2n2

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Let's assume by contradiction that **there is** a positive integer solution.

Hence, each of these two equations essentially yields a [Pythagorean Triplet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple):

- The equation $p^2=m^2+n^2$ yields $[m<n<p]$
- The equation $s^2=4m^2n^2+p^2$ yields $[2mn<p<s]$ or $[p<2mn<s]$

The $[2mn<p<s]$ triplet is ruled out because:

- $m,n,p$ are the sides of a triangle $\implies p<m+n$
- $m,n$ are larger than $1 \implies m+n<2mn$

So we are left with the triplets $[m<n<p]$ and $[p<2mn<s]$.

Hence, there must be positive integers $a>b$ and $c>d$ such that:

- $m   = a^2-b^2$
- $n   = 2ab$
- $p   = a^2+b^2$
- $p   = c^2-d^2$
- $2mn = 2cd$
- $s   = c^2+d^2$

Comment: How do you know m can be expressed as a^2-b^2?I think $m=k(a^{2}-b^{2}),n=k*2ab$or$m=k*2ab,n=k(a^{2}-b^{2})$,k is the greatest common divisor of m and n,and a,b are coprime and one of them is odd,the other is even

Comment: @windwalk: Please visit the link published in my answer, and go to the beginning of the 'Generating a triple' section.

Comment: How to express (9,12,15) in ($a^{2}-b^{2},2ab,a^{2}+b^{2}$) style?Not every  Pythagorean Triplet can be expressed like this:($a^{2}-b^{2},2ab,a^{2}+b^{2}$).M=m/k,N=n/k,P=p/k,Q=2mn/k,S=s/k,then $$M^{2}+N^{2}=P^{2},P^{2}+Q^{2}=S^{2}$$

Comment: k=gcd(m,n),then $$M=a^{2}-b^{2},N=2ab,P=a^{2}+b^{2},Q=2k(a^{2}-b^{2})*2ab$$,can you tell me how to find contradictions ?